# how to make sql select with subqueries faster

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a complex SQL select statement. It is very poor in performance. I was wondering how I can make it faster.

```
SELECT 
     ............
     ............
     CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(T.ONHAND) - SUM(T.RESERVED) FROM LV_001_01_STINVTOT T WHERE STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF AND T.INVENNO IN (13,4)) < 0 THEN 0
          WHEN (SELECT SUM(T.ONHAND) - SUM(T.RESERVED) FROM LV_001_01_STINVTOT T WHERE STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF AND T.INVENNO IN (13,4)) >= 0 
            THEN  (SELECT SUM(T.ONHAND) - SUM(T.RESERVED) FROM LV_001_01_STINVTOT T WHERE STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF AND T.INVENNO IN (13,4))
     END AS MIKTAR
     ............
     ............
FROM XXX AS S
```

In the CASE above, I know I had used the same subquery 3 times and makes the whole script too slow.

How can I make it faster?

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan?

Comment: what do you mean? my select statement is much longer but I just posted the CASE part

Comment: You're running the exact same subquery 3 times. Why?

Comment: If the subquery return a negative number, I convert it to ZERO. It is a positive number, then I display that positive number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. Please note the IIF function is available in SQL Server 2012 and above.

```
SELECT 
IIF (SUM(ISNULL(T.ONHAND,0)) - SUM(ISNULL(T.RESERVED,0)) < 0, 0, SUM(T.ONHAND) - SUM(T.RESERVED) )
FROM XXX AS S
LEFT JOIN LV_001_01_STINVTOT T ON STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF AND T.INVENNO IN (13,4)
```

Comment: This is the correct one. Thanks a lot. I was not putting the T.INVENNO IN (13,4) next to the LEFT JOIN. I was putting it at the main where close at the bottom.

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ Yes, you need to put as part of the JOIN clause. If you put it in the WHERE clause it will act like an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Thank you very much, very clean solution

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ No problem, glad to be of help.

Comment: I am very happy to see that my question caught everyone's attention . Thank you very much to all

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `left Join` instead of `subquery`

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Sum(T.ONHAND) - Sum(T.RESERVED) < 0 THEN 0
         ELSE Sum(T.ONHAND) - Sum(T.RESERVED)
       END
FROM   XXX s
      LEFT JOIN LV_001_01_STINVTOT T
         ON   t.STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF
         AND  T.INVENNO IN ( 13, 4 )
```

Or

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (SELECT Sum(T.ONHAND) - Sum(T.RESERVED)
               FROM   LV_001_01_STINVTOT T
               WHERE  STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF
                      AND T.INVENNO IN ( 13, 4 )) < 0 THEN 0
         ELSE (SELECT Sum(T.ONHAND) - Sum(T.RESERVED)
               FROM   LV_001_01_STINVTOT T
               WHERE  STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF
                      AND T.INVENNO IN ( 13, 4 ))
       END AS MIKTAR
FROM   XXX AS S
```

Or declare one variable store the subquery result in that variable.

```
DECLARE @sumdiff INT

SELECT @sumdiff = Sum(T.ONHAND) - Sum(T.RESERVED)
FROM   LV_001_01_STINVTOT T
WHERE  STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF
       AND T.INVENNO IN ( 13, 4 )

SELECT CASE 
         WHEN @sumdiff< 0 THEN 0
         ELSE @sumdiff
       END
FROM   XXX s
```

Comment: it is not the same as my question. The JOIN eliminates some rows from XXX

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ - Updated Check now

Comment: It still has the potential to duplicate rows and give wrong results, it's definitely not equivalent to the query used by op. What's more, since you are using a column from the `T` table on your filter, it is essentially an inner join

Comment: LEFT JOIN T then WHERE T.anything makes it an inner join.

Comment: This LEFT JOIN with this WHERE clause will be interpreted as an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     CASE  WHEN SUM(T.ONHAND) - SUM(T.RESERVED) < 0 THEN 0
         ELSE SUM(T.ONHAND) - SUM(T.RESERVED)
     END AS MIKTAR
FROM XXX AS S
LEFT JOIN LV_001_01_STINVTOT T  ON  T.STOCKREF = S.LOGICALREF  
                               AND  T.INVENNO IN (13,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN AVAILABLESTOCK<0 THEN 0
    WHEN RESULT>= 0 THEN ...
FROM XXX AS S,
(SELECT SUM(T.ONHAND)-SUM(T.RESERVED) AS AVAILABLESTOCK,STOCKREF  FROM LV_001_01_STINVTOT WHERE T.INVENNO IN (13,4)
GROUP BY STOCKREF ) LV
WHERE S.LOGICALREF =LV.STOCKREF
```

You can also try to save aggregated results of LV_001_01_STINVTOT in a Temp table and use that temporary table in sub queries. It depends on the actual size of LV_001_01_STINVTOT and its size with after aggregation with this condition "T.INVENNO IN (13,4)"